# Поисковая система sphinx на freebsd. Возможные проблемы?

Tags: apache, sphinx, freebsd

Имеется сервак на freebsd 8.2 + апач, кажется 1.3. Были ли у кого-нибудь проблемы с [sphinx](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%29)`ом при подобном наборе? Имеет ли смысл обновить до апач2?

Или дайте линк на актуальную тему.

Comment: Версия FreeBSD, которой Вы пользуетесь, уже не поддерживается, обновления безопасности к ней не выпускаются. По возможности рассмотрите переход на 9.3 (поддерживается до конца 2016 года) или 10.1+.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть здесь: [Sphinx. Установка и первичная настройка](http://livestreet.ru/blog/dev_documentation/366.html).